# Specify Constraints for two UIViews in percentage

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

Following image shows the design for the two UIView. The one in green should always be 20% and the yellow should always be 80%, in land scape or portrait.

I am missing on some constraint or content hugging change, so trying to fix.

Note: Content hugging and compression priority has default values.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The way I would do this is to set the dark green view top, left and right sides with 0 margin to the parent view, then set it's height equal to 20% of the superview (by setting it equal, then editing it).   Then setting the dark green view's top to have 0 margin from the light green view at the top, and zero margin from the superview for it's left right and bottom edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to have a fixed height of 212 for your top view. You want it to be 20% of it's super view.

1. You should delete your top view's height constraint of 212.
2. Select both your top view and its super view.
3. Add an equal height constraint.
4. Double click on that constraint and open it's size inspector.
5. Change multiplier to 0.2

[image: Example. First Item will likely say "View" for you.]

Comment: plus what I said in comment

Comment: @danh I thought the OP had those constraints already, but yes defiantly need the constraints Dan mentioned.

Comment: the key idea is attaching the subviews to each other at the bottom of the top and the top of the bottom, so the bottom gets exactly the 80% remainder height.  is that in there?   i can't read those things.

Comment: That worked. I did try to play with hugging and compression constraints but nothing worked, may be my approach was wrong.Any other use of "multiplier" apart from weight(percentage).